# Is there an order to call gridView.EndDataUpdate, gridView.EndUpdate, gridView.EndSummaryUpdate?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, batch-file, devexpress

If I want to use `gridView.EndDataUpdate (gridView.BeginDataUpdate)` and `gridView.EndSummaryUpdate (gridView.BeginSummaryUpdate)` together, which one should be the correct order?
Order 1:

```
gridView.BeginDataUpdate();
gridView.BeginSummaryUpdate();
...
gridView.EndSummaryUpdate();
gridView.EndDataUpdate();
```

Order 2:

```
gridView.BeginDataUpdate();
gridView.BeginSummaryUpdate();
...
gridView.EndDataUpdate();
gridView.EndSummaryUpdate();
```

And when I should use `gridView.EndUpdate (gridView.BeginUpdate)`, is there any order requirement?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BaseView.BeginUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_BeginUpdatetopic.aspx)/[BaseView.EndUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_EndUpdatetopic.aspx) methods locks the View and prevents subsequent **visual updates**. Any **data updates** cannot be avoided by using the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods. Instead, the [BaseView.BeginDataUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_BeginDataUpdatetopic.aspx) and [BaseView.EndDataUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_EndDataUpdatetopic.aspx) methods must be used.  Whenever summary items are added to a Grid View or their settings are modified, the grid automatically recalculates summaries. To prevent summary calculation until all summary items are properly initialized, use the [BeginSummaryUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_BeginSummaryUpdatetopic) and [EndSummaryUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_EndSummaryUpdatetopic.aspx) methods.
Here is the detailed description for all of these methods usage:
 - [Batch Modifications Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument773)

In your case you can enclose the data and summary updates with visual update as follows:

```
view.BeginUpdate();
try {
    ...view options modifications...

    view.BeginDataUpdate();
    try {
        ...data modifications...
    }
    finally{ view.EndDataUpdate(); } // real data update here

    view.BeginSummaryUpdate();
    try {
        ...summary modifications...
    }
    finally{ view.EndSummaryUpdate(); } // real summary recalculation

    ...another view options modifications...
}
finally{ view.EndUpdate(); } // real visual update
```